# Solving equations exam question involving triangles

Tags: linear-algebra, triangles

A triangle has the side lengths shown below. Find the length of each side, if the length of AC exceeds that of AB by $\frac{1}{2}$.

[image: triangle]

What I did:

$3x + 1 +\frac{1}{2}= 6x - 4 $

$6x - 3x = -4 - 1 - 1/2$

$3x = -5.5$

$x = -1.8333...$

But when I substitute I get the wrong answer.

Thank You and help is appreciated

Comment: "exceeds" means that it is the longer side.  You need to add 1/2 to the other side to balance them.

Comment: Length of $AC$ is _more_ than that of $AB$, that is, $\bar{AC}=\bar{AB}+1/2$.

Comment: O now I understand ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the length of the side AC exceeds AB of 1/2 it means that AC is AB+1/2. Therefore the right equation is

$$3x+1=6x-4+1/2$$ 
You get x=3/2